# Minimum Window Subsequence LeetCode Solution

Tags: java

**Problem statement** :
Given strings S and T, find the minimum (contiguous) substring W of S, so that T is a subsequence of W.

If there is no such window in S that covers all characters in T, return the empty string "". If there are multiple such minimum-length windows, return the one with the left-most starting index.

Example:
`Input:  S = "abcdebdde", T = "bde" Output: "bcde" Explanation:  "bcde" is the answer because it occurs before "bdde" which has the same length. "deb" is not a smaller window because the elements of T in the window must occur in order.`

```
public class MinimumWindowSubsequence {
  public String minWindow(String s, String t) {
    if (t.length() == 1) {
      int index = s.indexOf(t.charAt(0));
      return index == -1 ? "" : s.substring(index, index + 1);
    }
    int minLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String result = "";
    for (int leftPointer = 0; leftPointer < s.length(); leftPointer++) {
      char currentChar = s.charAt(leftPointer);
      if (currentChar == t.charAt(0)) {
        int counter = 1;
        int rightPointer = leftPointer + 1;
        while (rightPointer < s.length()) {
          if (counter < t.length() && s.charAt(rightPointer) == t.charAt(counter)) {
            counter++;
            if (counter == t.length()) {
              int currentLength = rightPointer - leftPointer;
              if (currentLength < minLength) {
                result = s.substring(leftPointer, rightPointer + 1);
                minLength = currentLength;
              }
              break;
            }
          }
          rightPointer++;
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

My code works but it does not pass the tests on LC which is fine with me. Can you please give me feedback on the code and help me cross-check the runtime of this algorithm? I think it is linear run-time.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems me testing is available only for premium accounts, could you add some other string tests to your post ?